# how to stop paplay

Tags: command-line, sound

`paplay a.ogg` plays `a.ogg` file from terminal. But the problem is it never stops until I press `Ctrl+c`. How can I stop it with a in line command. Is it possible to stop after maybe playing `n` times?

The only way it worked in my case is with a tiny script

```
paplay alert.ogg &
sleep length #length of audio or how long you want to play
kill -9 $!
```

any alternative will be helpful.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour. Which version of `pacat` are you using (`pacat --version`) ? `paplay` is actually an alias of `pacat -p` with format guessing. It should exactly play once.

Comment: `pacat 4.0
Compiled with libpulse 4.0.0
Linked with libpulse 4.0.0
`

Answer (score 1):

The only way it worked in my case is with a tiny script

```
paplay alert.ogg &
sleep length #length of audio or how long you want to play
kill -9 $!
```

any alternative will be helpful.

Comment: you should edit your question and add any progress you made on your problem in the question itself and do not to post it as answer.